# OAuth 2.0 is not enabled for method Error with jira cloud with App-script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth, jira

I have implemented oauth2 (3LO) using App-script for integrating Google Sheet and Jira. I have set var SCOPE = `read:jira-user read:jira-work write:jira-work`

When I use any get request, system works fine. But when I try to make put or post request, system throws error. See this image below:
[[image]][`enter code here`1]

See here my put request for edit an issue

[image]

I am not sure what is the issue here. I have checked that I have enabled oauth2 and as an administrator, I have all power. I have also proper scope. And this configuration works for any get request but it does not work with POST and PUT requests.

**Could you please let me know if you have an idea or clue how I can make it work or is there anything I can check to make sure my confirmation is right for POST or PUT requests?**

```
function updateIssue() {
  var service = getService();
  var issueIdOrKey = 'CP-16'

  Logger.log(service.hasAccess());

  if (service.hasAccess()) {

    var data = `{

      "summary":"New summary version 1"

    }`;

    var route = `/rest/api/3/issue/${issueIdOrKey}`;
    var cloudid = getCloudId(service);

    var url = 'https://api.atlassian.com/ex/jira/' + cloudid + route;

    Logger.log(url);
  
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
     'Method': 'PUT',
      headers: {
      //'Method': 'PUT',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken(),
      // Convert the JavaScript object to a JSON string.
      'ContentType': 'application/json' //, 'payload': JSON.stringify(data)

      },
      'payload': JSON.stringify(data)
    });


    var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
   
  }

}
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide your current script as a text data instead of the image?

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thanks for your response. See the post again for the code

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the text data of your script. From your provided text script, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direct solution to your issue, I apologize. At that time, please show the error message and please provide the official document of the API you want to use. By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Please include [example] not images.

Answer (score 2):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, at `var data =` {"summary":"New summary version 1"}`;,` data` has already been converted to the string.
- When `'ContentType'` is used, I thought that it was `'Content-Type'`. But, in your script, I thought that `'contentType': 'application/json'` can be used outside of the request header.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function updateIssue() {
  var service = getService();
  var issueIdOrKey = 'CP-16'
  Logger.log(service.hasAccess());
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
    var data = { "summary": "New summary version 1" }; // Modified
    var route = `/rest/api/3/issue/${issueIdOrKey}`;
    var cloudid = getCloudId(service);
    var url = 'https://api.atlassian.com/ex/jira/' + cloudid + route;
    Logger.log(url);
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      'Method': 'PUT',
      'headers': { // Modified
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken(),
      },
      'contentType': 'application/json', // Added
      'payload': JSON.stringify(data)
    });
    var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that your access token and your endpoint, and your request body are valid values. Please be careful about this. If an error occurs, please show the error message and please provide the official document of the API you want to use. By this, I would like to confirm it.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: I got same error with your modification. Here is the official doc https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-issues/#api-rest-api-3-issue-issueidorkey-get                                                                                                                                              My access token, and body are valid. I can use the same access token for GET requests and it works as expected. For end point, you will find it in the above link.

Comment: Here is error when I run the script after your modifications                                                                              Error 
Exception: Request failed for https://api.atlassian.com returned code 403. Truncated server response: {"errorMessages":["OAuth 2.0 is not enabled for method: POST /rest/api/3/issue/CP-16"]} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
updateIssue @ UpdateRecords.gs:22

Comment: @Bablu Banik Thank you for replying. About `I got same error with your modification.`, I apologize for this. About `Here is the official doc developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/…`, unofrtunately, I cannot find the document of the API `var url = 'https://api.atlassian.com/ex/jira/' + cloudid + route;` you want to use. Where can I see it?

Comment: On the same link you will find the followings                                                          
Other integrations
For integrations that are not Forge or Connect apps, use OAuth 2.0 authorization code grants (3LO) for security (3LO scopes are shown as for operations OAuth scopes required). See OAuth 2.0 (3LO) apps for details.

The URIs for OAuth 2.0 (3LO) app REST API calls have this structure:

https://api.atlassian.com/ex/jira/<cloudId>dd/rest/api/3/<resource-name>

For example, https://api.atlassian.com/ex/jira/35273b54-3f06-40d2-880f-dd28cf8daafa/rest/api/3/issue/DEMO-1

Comment: @Bablu Banik Thank you for replying. From your reply, I couldn't find the document of the API you want to use. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can you provide the official document of the API you want to use?

Comment: This is the official doc : api.atlassian.com/ex/jira/<cloudId>dd/rest/api/3/   and I am using oauth2 3LO

Comment: @Bablu Banik Thank you for replying. From `This is the official doc : api.atlassian.com/ex/jira/<cloudId>dd/rest/api/3/ and I am using oauth2 3LO`, unfortunately, I cannot see the document. Where can I see the document? This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill again.

Comment: @Bablu Banik By the way, although I guessed that you have already confirmed, from your error message, the status code `403` can be seen. It means `The HTTP 403 Forbidden response status code indicates that the server understands the request but refuses to authorize it.`. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) For example, your API might not be able to be accessed with the POST method from the Google side? I'm worried about this.